# How do I show a UIPickerView when a button is pressed?

Tags: swift

I am using a `UIPickerView` (Swift 3) to filter my list based on their category. But how to show the picker view on my Button. How the codes is?

Comment: What code have you written so far, and what was the result of it versus the expected result?

Comment: The picker view doesn't happen/showing in the UI. I want to make, when we clicked the button, the list of category will show up. How am I going to show you my codes?

Comment: You can edit your question to include snippets of them there.  The **help** link can provide the markdown information to format `code` as well.

Answer (score 0):

when you click this button, you can add to superView or hidden by setting.